# VB - Unchecking Check Boxes in a Group Box: Answer doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, groupbox

I found a possible answer to my question on how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060917/vb-unchecking-check-boxes-in-a-group-box)

However the code from that question:

```
Sub UnCheckBoxes()
Dim ChkBox As CheckBox = Nothing
    ' to unchecked all
    For Each ChkBox As Object In Worksheets("Check sheet").Report_Checks.Controls
        If TypeOf xObject Is CheckBox Then
            ChkBox = xObject
            ChkBox.Checked = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Produces a 'Compile error: syntax error'.  Any help appreciated

Comment: You are using xObject instead of ChkBox in the `If TypeOf ...` part. xObject has not been declared. Edit your For Each so that it says `For Each xObject` again and it will work. The below comment would require you to cast ChkBox as a CheckBox to access it's properties again.

Comment: Shouldn't `If TypeOf xObject Is CheckBox Then` be `If TypeOf ChkBox Is CheckBox Then`. Also you don't need to declare it at the top.

Answer (score 3):

As per my comment. Switch your code to:

```
Sub UnCheckBoxes()
    Dim ChkBox As CheckBox = Nothing
    ' to unchecked all
    For Each xObject As Object In Worksheets("Check sheet").Report_Checks.Controls
        If TypeOf xObject Is CheckBox Then
            ChkBox = xObject
            ChkBox.Checked = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The xObject object is used as a generic class to loop through all of your controls in Report_Checks. The If statement then checks if xObject is of type CheckBox. ChkBox is then set to xObject so that you can access it's CheckBox properties and assign `.Checked = False`

Comment: Make sure you place the sub within a Class or Module.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution which uses OfType to remove the need for checking the object type each time

```
For Each ChkBox As CheckBox In Worksheets("Check sheet").Report_Checks.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)
    ChkBox.Checked = False
Next
```

Comment: If you still have this `Dim ChkBox As CheckBox = Nothing` alongside `For Each ChkBox As Object In Worksheets("Check sheet").Report_Checks.Controls` then yes you will still have the error..